# Javascript function inside another function with foreach

Tags: javascript, ajax

I did not post whole C# code, otherwise it will get messy but if need be I'll edit it. I have user with fullname and id, my response have more user under 1 user. I need to fill the list under the each user with its own list.

Myfunction is to show place that I want to fill. Priority user list will be displayed as another list under its own user. I don't know how to do this foreach, I am new to javascript.

```
$(".selectstudent").click(function() {
  var test = this;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Courses/GetUserList",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      id: this.id
    },
    success: function(resp) {
      $('.inlist').empty();
      $.each(resp,
        function(i) {
          $(".inlist").append($("<div class=\"container\"> <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn\" data-target=\"#id" + resp[i].ID + "\">+</button> <label> " +
            resp[i].FullName + "</label>" +
            "<div class=\"collapse\" id=\"id" + resp[i].ID + "\" <ul>" + 

            myfunction(resp[i].PriorityUserList) + "</ul></div > </div > <div>"));
          //resp[i].PriorityUserList[0].FullName
        }
      );
    },
    failure: function(response) {
      alert(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function(response) {
      alert(response.responseText);
    }
  });

  $("#myModal").modal();
});

myfunction(variable) {
  variable.foraech(afunction(i)) {
    return "<li id=/" variable[j].ID + ">" + variable[j].FullName + "</li>"
  });
}
```

[image: This is the image of list i created]

Comment: Declare the second function outside your first function (above it), then just call it in the second.

Comment: @sirence Problem is not declaring, problem is fill the list with my own object with foreach or something like that.

Comment: You just want a foreach for every entry in your list?

Comment: @Sirence i want foreach for every user's list to type everything in the list

Comment: template literals would make your code more readable

Comment: @marzelin for outside of html part? I guess you are right

Comment: use map instead `foreach` return the result and use `join()` to transform an array to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `map` instead `forEach` and use `join` on returned array to transform an array to string then return the string of html.

```js
function myfunction(PriorityUserList) {
  return PriorityUserList.map(({ ID, FullName }) =>
    `<li id="${ID}">${FullName}</li>`
  ).join(' ');
}


/// demo code

const PriorityUserList = ["mark", "tom", "adam"]
  .map((FullName, i) => ({ ID: i, FullName }))

document.querySelector("body")
 .insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", myfunction(PriorityUserList));
```

Comment: This is almost true, there is a conflict with id(i guess top id and this is conflicts), i try to solve it. After i solve, if this works, i ll sign it as a answer. Looking for it.

Comment: I ll check that problem myself, thanks for this, this solves!